# .net core 2.1 with react testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been developing React and .net core 2.1 web api and have them separately. Now I would like to run tests on client side only and I am not sure if what I want to do is possible. I have create-react-app client side application and there's a single test that renders the entire application.

```js
it("renders without crashing", () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
});
```

When I try to run npm test in the terminal, I have the server running. (I tried running it in visual studio and in cmd with `dotnet run`. All it does is this error:

```
TypeError: Network request failed
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\fetch.js:436:16)alTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\fetch.js:436:16)                         ingWebsite\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:289:32)
at XMLHttpRequest.callback.(anonymous function) (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackkingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:219:27)ingWebsite\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTckingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:166:7)arget-impl.js:289:32)                                                                          lTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:122:7)
at invokeEventListeners (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ReactGoalTractGoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:87:17)kingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:219:27)   GoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\generated\EventTarget.js:61:35)
at invokeInlineListeners (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ReactGoalTrakingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:405:16)ckingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:166:7)   ite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:315:13)
at EventTargetImpl._dispatch (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ReactGoakingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\Document-impl.js:146:21)lTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:122:7ite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\Window.js:362:29))                                                                                              TrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\build\index.js:44:19)
at EventTargetImpl.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ReackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\build\runTest.js:102:17)tGoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:87:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\generated\EventTarget.js:61:35)    at XMLHttpRequest.abort (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:405:16)    at Object.abort (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:315:13)
at RequestManager.close (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\Document-impl.js:146:21)    at Window.close (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\Window.js:362:29)
at JSDOMEnvironment.dispose (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\build\index.js:44:19)    at Promise.resolve.then (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\build\runTest.js:102:17)
at <anonymous>    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Here's my startup configuration:

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

Is my configuration incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to run npm test in the terminal, I have the server running. (I tried running it in visual studio and in cmd with dotnet run. All it does is this error:
>
> ```
>    TypeError: Network request failed
>    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (C:\Users\Tomas\source\repos\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ReactGoalTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\fetch.js:436:16)alTrackingWebsite\ClientApp\node_modules\whatwg-
> ```

The error happens because the components you rendered in test do not get a correct URL . Let's say :

1. Your ASP.NET Core listens on http://localhost:5001
2. Your React Dev Server listens on port 57301

When you run the test by `npm test`, it will render those react components. However, if your react components fetch requests from server when mounted, **it has no idea about the correct server port and then throw an error of `Network request failed`** .

To fix the bug , simply invoke the following command :

```
react-scripts test --env=jsdom --testURL=https://localhost:50001/
```

Or change the `npm test` script in your `package.json` into :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --testURL=https://localhost:50001/",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

**Update :**

if you're using fetch api , don't forget to mock a fetch  :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^1.6.6"
}
```

setup :

```
global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock')
```

Comment: I am trying it right now, and am a bit confused as of where I should place setup code. I will write later when I figure it out.

Comment: @merlinabarzda Anywhere you can make sure the setup is executed will be ok . For a testing purpose ,  since you have only one test case , you could simply add the setup on the top of you `App.test.js` to check the test result .

Comment: Okay, so I finally managed to run it, thanks a lot to you. Had some problems due to package issues as it turned out, and needed to install jest-cli. (I wasn't the first one getting that). :)